# How to create an array of integers from a file, using QFile, c++

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

Im using qtCreator

I have a file `file.txt` like:

`n
 a1 a2 a3.. an
 b1 b2 b3.. bn
 n1 n2 n3.. nn`

n is the size of the matrix.

I need to create an array from dat file but using QFile, not ifstream.

Comment: What have you tried?, please, show your code.

Comment: Why do you need QFile?

Comment: add more information and the code, then its easier to know your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggested solution to store data from txt file into an array of numbers

```
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QVector>
#include <QStringList>

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    QFile data("dat.txt");
    if (!data.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        std::cout << "txt file can't be opened..." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    QString matrixStrSize;
    QTextStream in(&data);
    in >> matrixStrSize;

    int matSize = matrixStrSize.toInt();

    QVector< QVector<int> > matrix;


    while (!in.atEnd()) {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        if(!line.isEmpty()){
            QStringList numsStr = line.split(" ");
            QVector<int> temp;
            for(int i(0); i < matSize; ++i){
                temp.push_back(numsStr[i].toInt());
            }
            matrix.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    // Print data 
    std::cout << "mat[" << matSize << "][" << matSize << "] = " << std::endl;
    for(int i(0); i < matSize; ++i){
        for(int j(0); j < matSize; ++j)
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The text file in my case is

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

The output of the preceding code is

```
mat[5][5] =
1 2 3 4 5
5 6 7 8 9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

Comment: For downvoters, this is a suggested solution. I don't see any problem with my code. The code is just working fine so give me a break

Comment: The code is working fine, but rather tenuously so. 1. Extraneous spaces will result in a matrix with bogus data. 2. There's no error checking. 3. You're reading integers and storing them as doubles. 4. You could use `reserve` since you know the number of columns. 5. Error I/O can be done via `qWarning()`, `qFatal()`, etc. 6. `qDebug()`/`qInfo()` will automagically take care of a vector-of-vectors-of-double. (some of the foregoing are less important than others)

Comment: @KubaOber, I've forgotten to correct this line `QVector<double>` because at the first attempt, I though the OP wants a general approach but I've re-read it and it was about integers. Regarding the points, this code is not meant to very optimized, so I don't believe the code deserves a downvote.

Comment: The code works with the format the OP is asking for. Handling different formats is a completely different issue. I don't see why I need to try your inputs.

Comment: It's completely arbitrary how you read OP's "format". You can't know whether the example provided is a specialization or a generalization :) If you're thinking of the "continue this pattern" nonsense from "intelligence" tests - that's never a good way to interpret software specs. If you're nitpicking, note that all of OPs lines begin with a space :) I didn't downvote anything either. Anyway, this is all fake internet points. Don't worry about them.

Comment: Yes but note my note "*The text file in my case is*"

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to write a `QTextStream::operator>>` overload that parses the matrix.

Assuming that there's only one matrix in the file, below is a complete example meant to be correct, i.e. I didn't intentionally cut any corners and the code is supposed to work fine in real-life situations - namely, it should detect all errors. I chose a matrix format where line breaks don't play any role - it wasn't obvious from the question whether they should.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/file-matrix-read-44466934
#include <QtCore>
#include <cstdlib>

using Matrix = QVector<QVector<double>>;

// A valid matrix has a positive row size, and consists of a non-zero number of
// rows all having the same number of elements equal to the row size.
// Whitespace separates the elements.
// The matrix will be left unchanged if it doesn't conform to spec above, or if
// an I/O error had occurred. Non-conforming matrices set a ReadCorruptData
// status.
QTextStream & operator>>(QTextStream & in, Matrix & out) {
   Matrix matrix;
   int columns;
   in >> columns;
   if (in.status() != QTextStream::Ok)
      return in;
   if (columns <= 0) {
      in.setStatus(QTextStream::ReadCorruptData);
      return in;
   }
   for (int col = 0; !in.atEnd(); col++) {
      double element;
      in >> element;
      if (in.status() == QTextStream::ReadPastEnd)
         break;
      if (in.status() != QTextStream::Ok)
         return in;
      if (col >= columns)
         col = 0;
      if (col == 0) {
         matrix.push_back({});
         matrix.back().reserve(columns);
      }
      matrix.back().push_back(element);
   }
   if (!matrix.isEmpty() && matrix.back().size() == columns)
      out = matrix;
   else
      in.setStatus(QTextStream::ReadCorruptData);
   return in;
}
```

And a test harness:

```
const char
rawData[] = "5\n"
            "1 2 3 4 5\n"
            "5 6 7 8 9\n"
            "10 11 12 13 14\n"
            "15 16 17 18 19\n"
            "20 21 22 23 24";

int main()
{
   auto data = QByteArray::fromRawData(rawData, sizeof(rawData)-1);
   QBuffer file(&data);
   if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
      return qCritical("Input file can't be opened."), EXIT_FAILURE;
   QTextStream in(&file);
   Matrix matrix;
   in >> matrix;
   qDebug() << matrix;
   Matrix compare{{1,2,3,4,5}, {5,6,7,8,9}, {10,11,12,13,14}, {15,16,17,18,19}, {20,21,22,23,24}};
   Q_ASSERT(matrix == compare);
}
```